# Can I control my android phone using code from a pc or tablet?

Tags: android

I would like to control my android phone using code from a pc or tablet, is this possible at all?

I know there is EventInjector in blackberry development, something like this available with android?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `adb` is a command line tool for development and debugging. Over USB or TCP, you can open a command shell, copy files, uninstall applications and some other things like that. You can even install applications, run them and debug them.

If you just want a command shell over TCP, you can also install an SSH server.